# Combining member access operators with overloaded call operator

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Given a class `Foo` with overloaded `Boo* operator()(unsigned int)`, how should the overloaded operator be accessed?

I originally tried

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr(new Foo);
Boo* boo_ptr = foo_ptr(1);
```

But this doesn't work, so I tried:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr(new Foo);
Boo* boo_ptr = foo_ptr->(1);
```

but this doesn't work either (and I didn't really expect it to). Instead I have to do

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr(new Foo);
Boo* boo_ptr = (*foo_ptr)(1);
```

Which is more verbose than declaring a method in `Foo` such as `ByIndex(unsigned int)` instead (and making it shorter and more succinct was why I overloaded the operator in the first place).

Is there a way to do this without having to use the `*` operator to get the base value of the pointer?

Comment: I haven't actually in my code - I just had that in the example here to emphasise that I started with a pointer

Comment: @Columbo Didn't read the whole way through apparently. I don't actually understand the question then. "Is there a way to get an object from a pointer without `*`"?

Comment: @Columbo There, changed the uses of `new` to `std::unique_ptr` which is what I actually use in my code there. I just didn't bother with that the first time since it doesn't affect the question at all.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this so much? It's not poorly asked, and it's a valid question for those who don't know the inner workings of C++ very well. It's unfortunate people are downvoting this without even stating why the downvote is deserved (which is important for the OP to be able to improve!). +1 from me.

Comment: @Kvothe There is a difference. Smart pointers *might* overload `operator()`. `unique_ptr` does not, but we couldn't know which one you use, could we.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to dereference the pointer to access the object; so the only ways to call the operator are

```
(*foo_ptr)(1)
foo_ptr->operator()(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was puzzled as to why I couldn't get it to work with `->`. I hadn't realised it would need to be preceded by `operator`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make a reference:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr(new Foo);
Foo& foo_ref = *foo_ptr;

Boo* boo_ptr = foo_ref(1);
```

Besides that, I think Mike Seymour is correct that there's nothing else you can do to invoke `operator()`.

Comment: Hadn't though of this, but I guess this method would be just as verbose as declaring a member function instead of overloading the paranthesis operator